# DynamoDB regularly recieve error: "The AWS Access Key Id needs a subscription for the service"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am running into a strange issue with aws's dynamoDB.

Regularly the dynamoDB aws UI and API calls return the following error:

> The AWS Access Key Id needs a subscription for the service

I have a feeling that it's an aws related issue since it happens in the UI and only about 1 in 10 api calls fail with the message.  Any suggested solutions would be appreciated.

API Error:

```
An uncaught Exception was encountered

Type: Aws\DynamoDb\Exception\DynamoDbException

Message: Error executing "PutItem" on "https://dynamodb.us-west-2.amazonaws.com"; AWS HTTP error: Client error: `POST https://dynamodb.us-west-2.amazonaws.com` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response: {"__type":"com.amazon.coral.service#SubscriptionRequiredException","message":"The AWS Access Key Id needs a subscription (truncated...) SubscriptionRequiredException (client): The AWS Access Key Id needs a subscription for the service - {"__type":"com.amazon.coral.service#SubscriptionRequiredException","message":"The AWS Access Key Id needs a subscription for the service"}
```

UI error:

> The AWS Access Key Id needs a subscription for the service (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: SubscriptionRequiredException; Request ID: ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, I believe the "The AWS Access Key Id needs a subscription for the service" error is caused by old accounts created when you had to opt in to each individual service.

See this forum post, [forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=609804](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=609804), for more info.

After creating a completely new AWS account I haven't received the error once, still waiting to see if it can be resolved in my older account.

Comment: AWS support provided a couple of links to subscribe that seemed to work.  But I stuck with he new account to avoid any potential further issues.